# Route REST request based on extension format in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, http, rest

Using MVC as my service host, how can I route an incoming request for a piece of data based on the requested file extension format? For example, I have a controller action named Case and I want to return information about that case in a specific format which is specified as an extension on the request URL:

http://localhost/Case.xml would return the data in XML format

http://localhost/Case.json would return the data in json format

I know http content types can be used for specifying the request type, but I want the consumer to be able to make the request using just a URL and be able to specify the format of the data being returned. I would expect the extension on the request to override the http content type if one was specified.

I'm certainly open to other suggestions as a means of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC Beta 4 has Web API that supports this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that, unfortunately developing in Beta frameworks isn't sanctioned by our corporate software development policy.

Comment: I thought this has a Go live License.

Comment: @suing  It does.  However, some companies don't like using beta frameworks and I don't really blame them.

Comment: It looks like that's the way to go if we were to use MVC and it was out of beta. We decided to go with WCF as our service host so I think it's fair to give you this question. +1 to @DarrelMiller for his comment on abiding by company policies, sometimes it's just out of the developers hands unfortunately. :)